# Posting the message body to a different PHP page when the Submit event occurs in Contact Form

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form-7

I bid according to the data in the form sent by my customers. I need to transfer the data in the message body to a different page. How can I do this with JavaScript?

How can I export the HTML output of the form (in the picture below) to a different PHP page?

[image: See this image].

How can I post the message body (HTML output in email) section in a different PHP page with javascript when the `wpcf7mailsent` or `wpcf7submit` events occur?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with Javascript?  Can you do it with PHP?  What do you mean as far as another page? Is this a specific page, can there be a specific page template?

Comment: I can't catch the form sent using php due to lack of information. No matter how i do, i just need to post to another php page. For example "var inputs = event.detail.inputs;"
Can we print the message body (sent as an e-mail) like this way? Actually, what I want to do is save the email output of the message body to another database. I'm really stuck.

Comment: But you can catch the variables in PHP using `wpcf7_before_send_mail` then you catch your data and push to other database using an API or just `$wpdb->query`

Comment: I just can't access the HTML output of the message body. I can access the input data from the code I mentioned above. However, I cannot access the E-mail output of the form. How can we do this with PHP or Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it and share the results?

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'func_name');

function func_name($contact_form)
{
    //get mail property
    $mail = $contact_form->prop('mail'); //returns array 
    echo $mail['body'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function int_reg($contact_form)
{
    //Get the form ID
    $form_id = $contact_form->id();

    if ($form_id == 4645) {
        global $wpdb;
        $formtypeid = "1";

        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ($submission) {
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        }

        //spe data
        $v_yourName = $posted_data['username'];
        $v_yourMail = $posted_data['usermail'];

        $mail = $contact_form->prop('mail'); // returns array 

        $wpdb->insert('form_sub',
            array(
                'username' => $v_yourName,
                'usermail' => $v_yourMail,
                'formDetail' => $mail['body'],
                'formtypeid' => $formtypeid
            )
        );

        $mail['body'] .= '<br /> Co';
        $contact_form->set_properties(array('mail' => $mail));
    }
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'int_reg' );
```

Thanks for the reply. I wrote a code like this. Currently i can't pull the data in the message body, i can only get the tags; as you can see in the photos... How can I pull the data inside, not the tags.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh5at.jpg